# Ensemble runtime global lock

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-ensemble

When I try to start up my Ensemble production, I get the following error:

> ERROR ErrCanNotAcquireRuntimeLock: Could not acquire Ensemble runtime
>   global lock within timeout '10'

I figured I will disable all the services, processes and opperations and restart them individually to see which one is causing the error, however any action I take on the production takes a very long time and then comes back with the same error.

Googling the issue did not yield much, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the contents of your lock table while the production is not running -- it's likely that you have a job (or multiple jobs) that still have locks on the core Ensemble runtime globals. If you can identify the OS-level process(es) and can work out what they are actually doing, you should be able to terminate the OS processes. In both cases, you should perform this detection and termination from within Ensemble. You should be able to use the System Management Portal for both actions, or you can use the `^LOCKTAB` and `^JOBEXAM` CHUI utilities in the %SYS namespace to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restart Ensemble server, lock table should be cleared. This however doesn't help to find the cause of your problem.